# Is there a test suitable for the analysis of my data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, continuous-data

I am trying to compare the performance of pipelines. These pipelines have been sorted into two groups, Insulated and Non-Insulated. I have a total of roughly 60 pipes which are a combination of insulated and non insulated pipes. For each pipe I want to compare the cumulative steam injected into the pipe, as this will be my indicator of the performance of the insulation.

The issue I am running into is that the cumulative steam is dependent on both the injection temperature and pressure, both of which are continuous data. Pipe to pipe, these injection temperatures and pressures will differ.

I was wondering if it was possible to make an adequate comparison on the cumulative steam values while taking into account what I assume is an operational bias with the different conditions between the pipes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little general, but I'll try to help... I'll assume that temperature and pressure are in fact things outside of your control.

The simplest thing to do might be to compare different groups of pipes that all have similar pressure or temperature properties (i.e compare low_pressure_insulated with low_pressure_noninsulated and high_pressure_insulated with high_pressure_noninsulated).  What exactly are you trying to show?  If you just want to say that one insulation type is better, perhaps you could buy/find some pipes that are equally matched.  Or, if there is low correlation between insulation type and these temperature/pressure variables, and the distribution of temperature/pressure in the two groups is roughly comparable (even though different from pipe to pipe), you might be fine comparing them as-is (i.e. do you already have a somewhat random sample?)

Even though students come from different backgrounds, we might say that teaching method A is more effective at increasing test scores than teaching method B if we try A on 10k kids and B on 10k kids.  Although we know that test scores are also dependent on parental involvement, that difference should wash out in the average over a big random sample.  Although steam injection might depend on some variable besides, insulation, it won't matter much in a big enough random sample.

You could also maybe get a good feel for what's going on with a 3D plot, temperature on the X, pressure on the Y, steam injection on the Z/vertical axis, and then color the dots to show insulation type.

You could also try a regression model to account for temp/pressure, and see if insulation type has a big effect, but I think the plot might be the best place to start, unless you have to justify things really "statistically".